# Mid '|' in math?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, notation

What does this equation mean? What does the $|$ mean?

$446617991732222310 | mn(m^k - n^k)$

Here is the complete question for reference -

> What is the smallest positive integer $k$, such that for every ordered pair of integers $(m, n)$, we have
>
> $446617991732222310 | mn(m^k - n^k)$?

Please help

Comment: Division. $a \  | \  b$ means $a$ divides $b$ for two integers, $a, b$

Comment: It leaves no remainder?

Comment: Yes, if you generally draw that distinction.

Comment: I see in some of the comments and answers that the symbol means 'division'.  I think that is a bit of a misstatement.  Division is an operation that returns a numerical value (or values, depending on how one handles the remainder).  The symbol $\mid$ is for 'divides', which is a relation and gives a value of 'true' or 'false' as in $2 \mid 6$ is true; and $2 \mid 5$ is false.  This may seem like a fussy distinction, but perhaps not so much when one sees statements like $2 \mid 6 = 3$.

Comment: @paw88789: That is a fair distinction to adopt. I was being informal - wrongly so too - with the word "Division" in my comment. Wish I could say this was the first time I was criticised today for my language in solutions.

Comment: It's one of the most unfortunate notations in all of mathematics: A completely symmetric symbol denoting a highly asymmetric relation.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I agree 100%. Very well-described.

Comment: $ a\mid b\,$ in $\,R\,$ means  $\,a\,$ divides $\,b\,$ in  $\,R,\,$ i.e. $\,ar = b\,$ for some $\,r \in R,\,$ where $\,R\,$ is a commutative ring (if not specified then $\,R\,$ is the ambient ring, e.g. $\, R = \Bbb Z\,$ in elementary number theory). Note  $\,0\mid r\iff r = 0.\ \ $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For two integers $a,b$,
$$a\mid b$$
means $a$ divides $b$, i.e. $b=ak$ for some integer $k$.

Answer (score 3):

$a|b$ means that $a$ divides $b$.

Or equivalently $b=n.a$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, the symbol "$\mid$" means *division* (oddly enough, your question title actually somewhat refers to how "$\mid$" is typeset--this symbol is typeset by using the command `$\mid$`). More specifically, the notation $x_1\mid x_2$ means "$x_1$ divides $x_2$," where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are integers and we can represent $x_1\mid x_2$ algebraically as $x_2 = \ell\cdot x_1$, where $\ell$ is an arbitrary integer.

In the context of your problem, you are considering
$$
446617991732222310\mid mn(m^k - n^k),\tag{1}
$$
where $m,n,k$ are integers. What this *means*, per the description above, is simply that there exists an integer $\ell$ such that
$$
mn(m^k - n^k) = \ell\cdot 446617991732222310.
$$

**Side note:** One typographical thing you should be aware of is that using `$\mid$` is different from just using `$|$`: the spacing is different. Using `$\mid$`, we get the properly spaced expression in $(1)$. If we just use `$|$`, then we get the wonky spacing as follows:
$$
446617991732222310 | mn(m^k - n^k).
$$
I would edit your question to make this correction, but I'll leave it so you may see the difference.